# Apache Nutch skipping URLs & truncating

Tags: java, nutch, nutch2

In my nutch-site.xml, I add the following to stop truncating; however, during the fetch process, I get the following error. I want it to stop truncating and provide the results I need, which I assumed a -1 value would achieve. I'm using version 2.2.1. Any ideas?

```
<property>
    <name>http.content.limit</name>
    <value>-1</value>
    <description>The length limit for downloaded content using the http
        protocol, in bytes. If this value is nonnegative (>=0), content longer
        than it will be truncated; otherwise, no truncation at all. Do not
        confuse this setting with the file.content.limit setting.
    </description>
</property>
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed:
> name=fetch, jobid=job_local1185573074_0001    at
> org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:55)    at
> org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherJob.run(FetcherJob.java:194)  at
> org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherJob.fetch(FetcherJob.java:219)    at
> org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherJob.run(FetcherJob.java:301)  at
> org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)     at
> org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherJob.main(FetcherJob.java:307)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing the `http.content.limit` section in nutch-site.xml and adding the `parser.skip.truncated` and setting it to false.

```
<property>
    <name>parser.skip.truncated</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>Boolean value for whether we should skip parsing for truncated documents. By default this
        property is activated due to extremely high levels of CPU which parsing can sometimes take.
    </description>
</property>
```